# Custom renderer doesn't work in iOS + library

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, custom-renderer

I don't know why my Xamarin.Forms custom renderer doesn't work if I put it into a library and only on iOS, somebody could help me?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HtmlLabel), typeof(HtmlLabelRenderer))]
namespace Plugin.HtmlLabel.iOS
{
    public class HtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null) return;
            UpdateMaxLines();
            UpdateText();
        }
```

It works fine on Android, UWP and iOS if into the project.

https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a do-nothing `Initialize` static method to your `HtmlLabelRenderer` class to insure your renderer types are loaded *before* Forms

#### Example:

```
public static void Initialize()
{
}
```

#### Usage:

In your `AppDelegate` ***before*** `Forms.Init()`, call your Initialize method:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    Plugin.HtmlLabel.iOS.HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :) And I found another problem thanks to UWP, the PCL was missing. Android works without it but iOS and UWP don't.

Comment: Yes you don't need this on android